# postgis st_buffer from multipolygon returns polygon

Tags: postgis

i'm trying to buffer multipolygon like this

`MULTIPOLYGON(((18.601741790771 54.355655947711,18.613586425781 54.356856362498,18.616676330566 54.353855259767,18.601913452148 54.353255012915,18.601741790771 54.355655947711),(18.654441833496 54.360357371971,18.656673431396 54.366558427837,18.667144775391 54.3662583983,18.667659759521 54.36025734727,18.654441833496 54.360357371971),(18.71057510376 54.344750573821,18.719329833984 54.344750573821,18.720188140869 54.341748586892,18.707656860352 54.342449070119,18.71057510376 54.344750573821),(18.590068817139 54.344050129814,18.604831695557 54.344150193975,18.603458404541 54.339146687545,18.585090637207 54.340047363647,18.590068817139 54.344050129814)))`

it contains 4 separated polygons.

when I call

`select st_astext(
    gis.st_Buffer(
            gis.ST_GeomFromText(
                'MULTIPOLYGON(((18.601741790771 54.355655947711,18.613586425781 54.356856362498,18.616676330566 54.353855259767,18.601913452148 54.353255012915,18.601741790771 54.355655947711),(18.654441833496 54.360357371971,18.656673431396 54.366558427837,18.667144775391 54.3662583983,18.667659759521 54.36025734727,18.654441833496 54.360357371971),(18.71057510376 54.344750573821,18.719329833984 54.344750573821,18.720188140869 54.341748586892,18.707656860352 54.342449070119,18.71057510376 54.344750573821),(18.590068817139 54.344050129814,18.604831695557 54.344150193975,18.603458404541 54.339146687545,18.585090637207 54.340047363647,18.590068817139 54.344050129814)))'
            )
    ,0)
) as buffer`

i'm geiitng single polygon (actualy first element from multi):

`POLYGON((18.601741790771 54.355655947711,18.613586425781 54.356856362498,18.616676330566 54.353855259767,18.601913452148 54.353255012915,18.601741790771 54.355655947711))`

any idea how is it posibble to get polygon from buffered multipolygon?

Answer (score 1):

The multipolygon is not valid.

```
SELECT ST_IsValid(geom), ST_IsValidReason(geom)
FROM (
 SELECT 'MULTIPOLYGON(((18.601741790771 54.355655947711,18.613586425781 54.356856'
        '362498,18.616676330566 54.353855259767,18.601913452148 54.353255012915,'
        '18.601741790771 54.355655947711),(18.654441833496 54.360357371971,18.656'
        '673431396 54.366558427837,18.667144775391 54.3662583983,18.667659759521 '
        '54.36025734727,18.654441833496 54.360357371971),(18.71057510376 54.34475'
        '0573821,18.719329833984 54.344750573821,18.720188140869 54.341748586892,'
        '18.707656860352 54.342449070119,18.71057510376 54.344750573821),(18.5900'
        '68817139 54.344050129814,18.604831695557 54.344150193975,18.603458404541'
        ' 54.339146687545,18.585090637207 54.340047363647,18.590068817139 54.3440'
        '50129814)))'::geometry AS geom
) AS f;
NOTICE:  Hole lies outside shell at or near point 18.654441833496001 54.360357371970998

 st_isvalid |                     st_isvalidreason
------------+----------------------------------------------------------
 f          | Hole lies outside shell[18.654441833496 54.360357371971]
(1 row)
```

Invalid geometries have [bad implications for calculations, such as buffer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1060/what-are-the-implications-of-invalid-geometries). There is no point in picking apart your results any further.

Comment: My problem was icorrect MULTIPOLYGON definition. I've create it with pattern `MULTIPOLYGON(((__POLY__),(__POLY__), ... , (__POLY__)))` instead of `MULTIPOLYGON(((__POLY__)),((__POLY__)), ... , ((__POLY__)))`